# Kafka SSL(Connection with node Disconnected)

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I have configured SSL for kafka and I am having following two scenarios :-

A) When I configure the SSL listener on internal IP address (192.168.x.x), It works fine, 
B) When I configure the SSL listener on eth1 IP address(10.x.x.x) because that is the only IP of broker my client can reach, It doesnt work but throw following error :-

[2017-04-07 09:04:31,566] DEBUG Completed connection to node -1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-04-07 09:06:17,860] DEBUG Connection with devmoomsg1/10.228.175.83 disconnected (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
Adding more, When I try to check with the openssl whether the firewall is blockiing the ssl traffic I get output fine.

OpenSSL> s_client -host x.x.x.x -port 443 -debug
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x1500040 [0x1548fa0] (249 bytes => 249 (0xF9))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 f4 01 00 00-f0 03 03 58 e7 49 9b 1b   ...........X.I..
0010 - 60 ba 05 65 af 2e d3 2f-18 61 2a 87 ad b6 82 c6   `..e.../.a*.....
0020 - cd 9b d5 16 89 07 dd 65-38 1d 53 00 00 84 c0 30   .......e8.S....0
0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 13-c0 0a 00 a3 00 9f 00 6b   .,.(.$.........k
0040 - 00 6a 00 39 00 38 00 99-00 87 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a   .j.9.8.....2...*
...
0080 - 00 44 00 16 00 13 c0 31-c0 2d c0 29 c0 25 c0 0e   .D.....1.-.).%..
0090 - c0 04 c0 0d c0 03 00 9c-00 3c 00 2f 00 96 00 41   .........<./...A
....
00e0 - 04 01 04 02 04 03 03 01-03 02 03 03 02 01 02 02   ................
00f0 - 02 03 01 01 00 0f 00 01-01                        .........